# MySQL data files lost

Tags: mysql, windows

Recently reinstalled my system. Copied whole MySQL folder from `C:/Programdata`. Then copied  back to the same directory on new system, now the Navicat Premium shows the list of db's but when i'm trying to open one of db tables it shows me [image: http://prntscr.com/2s9e3]

I can't open any table. What to do? Ho can I fix it? Please help

Comment: This belongs to serverfault. In the future: use mysqldump to dump MYSQL databases.

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM tables?

Comment: innodb. can anyone help me with teamviewer?

Comment: Look here for how to copy a database from one system to another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586911/easiest-way-to-copy-a-mysql-database

Comment: And this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another

Comment: If you still have your old data copy it again, and make sure that you copy also my.ini. I've been doing that and had no problems. Also, try installing the same MySQL version as you had before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that your default DB storage was MyIsam and if you don't exported the databases then you doesn't have any solution to recover your data. The same thing happened to me and I spent lot of time with searching any good solution but I didn't find no one.

There is two solution to avoid these problems on the future: you export the database before the reinstall, or you can set the default DB storage to InnoDB and then the "copy back" solution it is working.

Maybe I was wrong (and I hope I was wrong :) ) I just described my own experience about this topic.

Comment: do you know scheduled backup application for this purpose?

Comment: sorry but I don't know any tool for this ... the best and simplest method: you do this manual before every system reisntall :)