# copy database from server to server with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to copy my database from one db to another db on my own server using php

1. db : reports
2. db : cards..

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: export from one server and import to other !!! can u do this ??? Or is their any other requirement .

Comment: If you have a manager like phpmyadmin or something you could just click the export button..

Comment: This haas been asked many times.. hope this one would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586911/easiest-way-to-copy-a-mysql-database

Comment: i just want to that using  a php script according to clients needs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of ways to backup and restore your db:

http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html

#6 teaches you how to do this with PHP and also how to restore your backup data.

Comment: It should work fine. Do you have the code what you tried? If so, posting it would help.